# Como seleccionar solo los hijos inmediatos de un parentNode?

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<ul class="parentNode" id="parentNode">
  <li><span>Inicio</span></li>
  <li><span>Categorias</span></li>
  <li><span>Contacto</span></li>
</ul>
```

Que metodo de JS podria implementar para selecionar solo los LI que son los hijos inmediatos pero exceptuar los SPAN, además cuando utilizo el "childNodes" me devuelve el array : [text, li, text, li, text, li, text] , disculpen la pregunta pero a que corresponde el elemento de la posicion 0 (text)? es decir, segun yo deberian haber 3 text, pero hay 4.

Una ultima pregunta, cuando intento seleccionar el UL con "getElementsByClassName" no me funciona y me devuelve "Undefined" pero cuando utilizo "getElementById" funciona correctamente, por que sucede eso?

```
var listItems = document.getElementById('parentNode').childNodes; //Funciona, devuelve "NodeList(7) [text, li, text, li, text, li, text]"


var ListItems = document.getElementsByClassName('parentNode').childNodes; //No Funciona, devuelve "undefined"
```

Comment: respecto de tu última pregunta deberias agregar tu código js para ayudarte, por otro lado checa [ask], y añade lo que hayas intentado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes probar con esto

```
document.querySelectorAll("#parentNode li").forEach(el => {
    console.log(el);
});
```

Esto obtendrá todos los `li` dentro de el elemento con el ID parentNode. Usa `querySelector` para obtener elementos usando selectores de CSS, esto solo retorna el primer elemento con el selector; para obtener todos los elementos usa `querySelectorAll`

Por lo que entendí en tu pregunta, no estás entendiendo el orden de los nodos, al ser `span` un nodo hijo y `li` el nodo padre e hijo a la vez de `ul`, `li` retornará la etiqueta con el `span` ya que es un nodo hijo.

### Edit

Con respecto a tu pregunta (ya editada) `getElementsByClassName` no te retorna un elemento, si no un array y tendrás que especificar la posición del elemento para recién poder ejecutar una función u obtener una propiedad

Comment: Es decir que childNodes me seleccionara todos los hijos, es decir no solo los inmediatos sino tambien los hijos de los hijos?

Comment: @VictorM03 eso es correcto, eso te retornará el `li` con todos sus otros hijos.

Comment: @anythingg el selector CSS mas acertado seria [_"el selector de hijos"_](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator), es decir,  `#parentNode > li`. Utilizando el selector que propones si algún `li` tuviera descendientes `li`, también los devolvería.

Answer (score 2):

Podrías utilizar [`Node.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children)

> La propiedad `children` es una propiedad de solo lectura que devuelve una colección `HTMLCollection` en vivo que contiene todos los elementos hijos del nodo en el que se llamó.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
let el = document.getElementById('parentNode');
console.log(el.children)
```

```html
<ul class="parentNode" id="parentNode">
  <li><span>Inicio</span></li>
  <li><span>Categorias</span></li>
  <li><span>Contacto</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Pero puedo usar esa propiedad para modificar el HTML?

Comment: Creo que entendí mal yo, a que te refieres con "Solo lectura"?

Comment: @VictorM03, con _"solo lectura"_ se refiere a que vos no podes modificar la colección (_agregar y/o quitar_) y con _"en vivo"_ se refiere a que si se modifican los hijos, la colección se actualiza automáticamente.

Comment: Es decir que el arreglo no lo puedo modificar, pero si puedo utilizar esa informacion del arreglo para acceder al DOM con Javascript?

Comment: @VictorM03, exacto, la colección tiene la referencia a los elementos del `DOM`, los cuales podes modificar sin ningún problema.

Comment: Ok amigo, muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo